# For what input and arguments will perl split give the result (""), if ever?

Tags: perl, split

To me, it looks like perl split can never give the result `("")`, i.e. a single-element list whose single element is the empty string. No matter what -- any input, any arguments to `split`. Can anyone show otherwise? And if not, is this a feature or a bug?

I wanted `split` to be able to for consistency, but alas:

> Note that splitting an EXPR that evaluates to the empty string always
>   produces zero fields, regardless of the LIMIT specified.

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html

E.g.:

```
$ echo ""|perl -ne 'chomp;print 0+split/x/,$_,-1'
0

$ echo "x"|perl -ne 'chomp;print 0+split/x/,$_,-1'
2

$ echo "xx"|perl -ne 'chomp;print 0+split/x/,$_,-1'
3

$ echo "xxx"|perl -ne 'chomp;print 0+split/x/,$_,-1'
4
```

Comment: Seems like a feature to me. How could you split nothing into one or more things?

Comment: Perl is supposed to return a single element containing the entire `$_` when `split` cannot split (no regexp match on the line). Perl breaks that "promise" when `$_` is `""`, returning an empty list instead.

Comment: In Perl the empty string `""` and the empty list `()` represent the same thing, which is false.

Comment: "I wanted `split` to be able to for consistency..." Can you expand on this? This seems like an XY problem.

Comment: workaround:  `split /:/, "$string:", $count`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: no, they represent very different things, though both are false.

Comment: @ysth yep, my mistake

Comment: @Hunter McMillen, That's not true. Empty lists aren't false. They aren't true either; it's simply impossible to evaluate whether an empty list is true or false.

Comment: @TSIBN More of a "notable exception" problem, but to your question, I had written code relying on "n separators always yield (n+1) fields" such that including separators in the result with a `/(...)/` regexp could always be counted on to result in an odd-number-sized list (n+(n+1)). Code broke on the exception.

Comment: @ikegami In terms of control flow they are considered false correct? `if ( () ) { print "Hello\n"; }` will not print for instance

Comment: @Hunter McMillen, There's no list there (except the one created by `print`). The stub operator returns undef in scalar context, and undef is false.

Comment: Can't find this "n separators always yield (n+1) fields" rule you mentioned.

Comment: `Anything in EXPR that matches PATTERN is taken to be a separator that separates the EXPR into substrings (called "fields") that do not include the separator.`

Comment: "If the `PATTERN` doesn't match at all, `split` returns the original string as a single substring. If it matches once, you get two substrings, and so on." -- Wall, Christiansen, & Schwartz

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is a tentative answer to my own question, pending any further information/correction that may come from others:

There are no inputs and arguments to perl `split` for which the result will ever be a single-element list containing the empty string.

In order to get a result consistent with the promises 1) "size of result will always be one more than the number of separators (regexp matches)" and 2) "if there are no separators, the result will always be a single-element list whose element is the whole original string", what would normally be a clean function call expression

```
split /.../
```

instead needs to be wrapped as follows, including an additional auxiliary array:

```
@s = split /.../, $_, -1 or push @s, "";
```

and then `@s` used where the `split /.../` normally would have been.

E.g.:

```
$ echo ""|perl -ne 'chomp;@s=split/x/,$_,-1 or push @s,"";print 0+@s'
1

$ echo "x"|perl -ne 'chomp;@s=split/x/,$_,-1 or push @s,"";print 0+@s'
2

$ echo "xx"|perl -ne 'chomp;@s=split/x/,$_,-1 or push @s,"";print 0+@s'
3

$ echo "xxx"|perl -ne 'chomp;@s=split/x/,$_,-1 or push @s,"";print 0+@s'
4
```

Or, alternatively, any code using bare `split /.../` and relying on either of the above "promises" needs to be put inside a guard `if (length) {...}` and the case of `length==0` handled in separate code.

Comment: This just seems like a less-readable version of ikegami's suggestion `length($_) ? split(...) : ""`.

Comment: I consider ikegami's less clear. For inputs other than `$_` it is also more fragile, requiring that that input be inserted for both `length` and `split` (and so expressions there are dangerous), e.g. `length(<some other var>) ? split /.../, <some other var>, -1 : "";`

Answer (score 6):

> *And if not, is this a feature or a bug?*

Not returning an empty string is not a bug. As per the documentation,

> Note that splitting an EXPR that evaluates to the empty string always produces zero fields, regardless of the LIMIT specified.

---

> *Can anyone show otherwise?*

It's highly unlikely that anyone will be able to find an input for which `split` return an empty string when it's documented to never return an empty string.

---

It sounds like you want a list of one item when the input is an empty string, so

```
length($_) ? split(..., $_, -1) : ""
```